# How to apply layout page to Hangfire dashboard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, hangfire

How to keep menus and other site context elements  when presenting Hangfire dashboard?

I am using Hangfire nuget package in my MVC 5 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution i encounter was to include the HangFire Dashboard in a view page, using iframe. 
The BackToSite button, called from the inside the `iframe`, causes the site to be render inside the `iframe`. It can be removed at `OwinStartup` by setting it to null like this:

```
app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
{
   AppPath = null,              
});
```

To apply the site theme to the dashboard can be done by creating a new PageView using Hangfire library, as show [here](https://gist.github.com/gandarez/9df813fc7d11f85c0d585a8257aedd79), but requires much more effort.